# No sound in lubuntu 20.04 after connecting bluetooth speaker

Tags: sound, lubuntu, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have lubuntu 20.04 installed on my machine. Everything was working fine for a couple of months. Everything was working fine until today when I've disconnected the bluetooth speaker from it. This is the first time I pair a bluetooth device with it. Now I cannot hear sound from my headphones (connected to the front or back sound panel). I've looked through the mixer configuration and the headphones are recognized, not muted, and the program (e.g. opera) is directed to play the sound there. Do you have any idea what might prevent from the sound playing there?

Bonus question, when I hit F3/F4/F5 in alsamixer in terminal the program quites instead of switching between the playback/input/all options.

---

**Edit**
I've looked again in alsamixer, the soundcard was muted (`MM`). Is there a way for me to prevent this automute?

Comment: Hi Im using Ubuntu Studio and after a year of hassle free use in general I'm up against this complete failure of audio sound output.
I too was using bluetooth and in my case it was doing voice recorder file transfer
from a Huawei mobile to this laptop.
The laptop has not had any sound from it, or through headphone socket, since i did
the bluetooth file transfer today.
I know this answer comes as a disappointment, but i just wanted to list my question with yours because there may be a connection to bluetooth usage that is reason for loss of sound functionality.

Answer (score 1):

select configure panel in task bar right click > widgets > volume control > * configure > select pulseaudio. try changing between pulseaudio/alsamixer. happened to me once gone after changing.